# parse response from subprocess call in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a scenario where I am running a subprocess call in for loop which outputs an unformatted dict like below.

input for subprocess call :

```
input1 = 
[
  {
    "name": "dem1",
    "id": "aabc123",
    "def": "beetui"
  },
  {
    "name": "dem2",
    "id": "aabc123453",
    "def": "lmtox"
  },
  {
    "name": "dem3",
    "id": "aabc123906y",
    "def": "detox"
  }
]

for val in input1:
        result = subprocess.call(['java', '-jar','app.jar', 'arg1', '-f', val.get("def"), '-r', val.get("id"), '-n', val.get("name")])
```

The value of `result` for 1st iteration in loop is :

```
{
  "id" : "kk",
  "version" : 1,
  "name" : "1",
  "description" : "880766",
  "timeCreated" : 1626432941497
}
```

For 2nd iteration :

```
{
  "id" : "kkl",
  "version" : 2,
  "name" : "1",
  "description" : "880789",
  "timeCreated" : 1626432941497
}
{
  "id" : "kkl",
  "version" : 1,
  "name" : "1",
  "description" : "880789",
  "timeCreated" : 1546432941497
}
```

for 3rd iteration :

```
{
  "id" : "fgh",
  "version" : 1,
  "name" : "1",
  "description" : "880766",
  "timeCreated" : 1626432941497
}
```

Now the question is I would like to iterate through this output and capture the latest version details.
currently I am doing this but I see the result value is showing `0` I am not sure why but in screen it outputs the `results`

What I have done :

```
final_data = []
    for val in input1:
            result = subprocess.call(['java', '-jar','app.jar', 'arg1', '-f', val.get("def"), '-r', val.get("id"), '-n', val.get("name")])
           #formatting the data in proper dict format
            sd_data = result.read().replace("\n","")
            sd_records = re.findall(r"\{[^\}]*\}", sd_data)
            sd_dictionaries = [json.loads(r) for r in sd_records]
            for sd_val in sd_dictionaries:
                maximum = max(sd_dictionaries, key=sd_dictionaries.get("version"))
                maxver = sd_dictionaries[maximum]
                temp_data = {"name": val.get("name"), "id" : val.get("id"), "def" : val.get("def"), "version" : maxver, "created" : sd_val.get("timeCreated")}
                final_data.append(temp_data)
```

Is this approach correct and how do I get the desired result? any help would be great

Comment: How do you define "latest version"? Is it the most recent timeCreated? Or is it just the highest version number?

Comment: @DarkKnight yeah most recent time created would also help

Answer (score 0):

**subprocess.call()** returns the exit code of the command it was running.
An exit code tells you if the command completed successfully (code 0) or failed (code other than 0).
Since your command completed successfully **result** is 0.

In order to receive the output of the command you better use **subprocess.check_output()** function.

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['java', '-jar','app.jar', 'arg1', '-f', val.get("def"), '-r', val.get("id"), '-n', val.get("name")])
```

More about the different functions of subprocess, here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: How do I read and format the data later from `subprocess.check_output` and also will it be a blocking call or nob-blocking?
since I am running it in loop i would need the process to wait for each call in loop rather parallely running, could you please help me elaborate

Comment: The data received from subprocess.check_output is a string (the same as you see in your terminal window when running this command) and it will be stored in result variable. subprocess.check_output is a blocking call, so it blocks execution of the following code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the most recent JSON structure (based on timeCreated), you could do it like this:-

```
import re
import json
import subprocess

input1 = [
    {
        "name": "dem1",
        "id": "aabc123",
        "def": "beetui"
    },
    {
        "name": "dem2",
        "id": "aabc123453",
        "def": "lmtox"
    },
    {
        "name": "dem3",
        "id": "aabc123906y",
        "def": "detox"
    }
]

def getMostRecent(inp):
    J=None
    for val in inp:
        args = ['java','-jar','app.jar','arg1','-f',val.get("def"),'-r',val.get("id"),'-n',val.get("name")]
        resp = subprocess.run(args, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
        for r in re.findall(r"\{[^\}]*\}", resp.stdout):
            _j = json.loads(r)
            if J is None or _j['timeCreated'] > J['timeCreated']:
                J = _j
    return J

print(getMostRecent(input1))
```

Note that since Python 3.5, run() is preferred to call()

Comment: But that `return j` would also have the values of `name`, `id`, `def` from `input1` ?
my desired output in this case is ex- for 2nd loop `[{
        "name": "dem2",
        "id": "aabc123453",
        "def": "lmtox",
        "timeCreated" : 1626432941497,
        "version" : 2}]`

Comment: also I would be running the data in loop so is subprocess.run blocking call ?
I would need to wait for the call to get finished as I dont want to run in parallel
subprocess call loop may go till 800 in number

Comment: subprocess.run() executes synchronously (blocking)

Comment: Thanks but `J` doesn't appends the data from input1 as I mentioned above :-(

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't works
`!!! TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
14:54:19.85 !!! When calling: subprocess.run(args, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)`

Comment: What Python version are you running? I tested this on 3.9.6 and it's fine

Comment: I ran it on 3.7

Comment: Did you copy'n'paste my code and run it? I ask because there is no way that anything in my code passed to subprocess.run() could be construed as being a tuple. As far as I can tell, this is compatible with 3.7

Comment: I resloved the issue, by adding `.decode()` , not sure why that occurred.
But the value of `J` is actually returning the entire data set which is not required.
I would only need the time created value (recent one) and appending that to the main data set(`input1`) which was passed as described in the question -- ex- .
`[{ "name": "dem2", "id": "aabc123453", "def": "lmtox", "timeCreated" : 1626432941497, "version" : 2}]`
currently the value of J is returning `{
  "id" : "kkl",
  "version" : 2,
  "name" : "1",
  "description" : "880789",
  "timeCreated" : 1626432941497
}`